# how to read the selected option in the multiple dropdown list in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

On the click of submit button, I want to send all the data by ajax call to the server. I'm trying to get the selected Text of dropdown list, it gives the text of first dropdown list for each iteration.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L7xy2kjz/10/.

**This is the result of what I tried** :

```
ScoreCard={"Heading":"pawar","parameters":[{"Name":"nikita ","Raiting":"ME","Score":"0"},{"Name":"mayuri","Raiting":"ME","Score":"0"}]},{"Heading":" schoool","parameters":[{"Name":"sss","Raiting":"ME","Score":"0"}]}
```

In the above code even after selecting the different options from the dropdown ie. `"Raiting":"ME"` . but the output displays the Text of first dropdown.

```
function GetObservationReview() {
    var parameters = {}, status;
    var ObservationArray = [];


    $('#ObservationEntry, .tblObservation').each(function () {

        var item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');            //get each row
        var hasclassparam = $(this).closest("tr").attr('name') === 'ObsevHeading';

        if (status == 'Parameters' && $(this).attr('name') === 'ObsevHeading') {   //if next tr is heading then push whole object in array till first heading

            metrics = {
                'Heading': Heading1,
                'parameters': paramarray     // paramNewArray
                //work in process
            }
            var stringyfydata = JSON.stringify(metrics);
            ObservationArray.push(stringyfydata);

            metrics = {};
            paramarray = [];
        }

        if ($(this).attr('name') === 'ObsevHeading') {    //if the current row having name as     heading

            status == 'heading';

            $.each(item, function (key, value) {
                if (key == 0) {
                    Heading1 = ($(value).text());
                 }

                //else if (key == 1) {
                //    TotalWeightage = ($(value).text());
                //} 
            });
        }

        if ($(this).attr('name') === 'ObsvParameters') {            //read parameters
            status = 'Parameters';
             var e = document.getElementById("dropDownLevelChangetrue");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            var islastchild = $(this).closest("tr").is(":last-child");   //last child
            MyLevels = {}; i = 1;
            $.each(item, function (key, value) {


                if (key == 0) {
                    parametername = ($(value).text());  
                }
                 if (key == 1) {

                   param_Raiting = (strUser); 
                 }
                if (key == 2) {
                    para_Score =($(value).text()); 
                }

           });

            parameters = {
                "Name": parametername,
                "Raiting": param_Raiting,
                "Score": para_Score


            }
            paramarray.push(parameters);

            if (islastchild === true) {                 // if row is last row add whole object in data

                metrics = {
                    'Heading': Heading1,
                    'parameters': paramarray  //parameter array that stores  Paameter name and its weightage



                }
                var stringyfydata = JSON.stringify(metrics);
                ObservationArray.push(stringyfydata);              //pushing whole object in data1 array

                paramarray = [];
                metrics = {};

            }

        }
    });

    alert("ScoreCard=" + ObservationArray);
    return ObservationArray;
}
```

**The expected result :**

```
ScoreCard={"Heading":"pawar","parameters":[{"Name":"nikita ","Raiting":"EE","Score":"0"},{"Name":"mayuri","Raiting":"ME","Score":"0"}]},{"Heading":" schoool","parameters":[{"Name":"sss","Raiting":"NI","Score":"0"}]}
```

Comment: All of your `select` elements has the same name `department` so js take those as one and get value only from one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are always taking value from the same element in these lines

```js
var e = document.getElementById("dropDownLevelChangetrue");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Try to get them by name or something. getById always gets the first one in DOM node and ends